# What should I take into consideration regarding the `jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive` parameter?

Tags: oracle, servlets, jakarta-ee, jersey

According to the Oracle documentation for [Building, Packaging, and Deploying RESTful Web Service Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/RESTF/deploy-restful-service.htm#RESTF179) there is a parameter `jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive` that can be used to modify the servlets configurations.

Example of web.xml file if a class that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` is not packaged. This is for Pre-3.0 Servlets:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
           <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
           <param-value>org.foo.myresources,org.bar.otherresources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
           <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive</param-name>
           <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        ...
    </servlet>
    ...
</web-app>
```

Now, there is not any documentation explaining exactly what does this parameter does and how to use it.

**Question:**

So, what should I take into consideration regarding the `jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive` parameter when Building, Packaging, and Deploying RESTful Web Service Applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the jersey github project ([jersey/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.java#L108](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.java#L108)) there is a formal description for this property:

> Sets the recursion strategy for package scanning.
>
> The value of`true` indicates that the [list of provided package
>   names](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.java#L86) should be scanned recursively including any nested packages.
>   Value of `false` indicates that only packages in the list should be
>   scanned. In such case any nested packages will be ignored.
>
> The property value MUST be an instance of `Boolean` type or a `String`
>   convertible to `Boolean` type.
>
> A default value is `true`.